# Understanding gulp-reactify workflow/structure

Tags: gulp, reactjs, browserify

Trying to understand how to integrate build systems like gulp into my Node/React workflow. Here is my naive understanding:
In development, you want to be compiling all JSX into plain JS on the fly. You do this with something like gulp and gulp-watchify. Upon updates to your files, gulp transforms [reactify] your files and bundles into it's own file.

Now this is the part I'm having trouble understanding. All examples I've seen seem to digest the main node file (app.js or main.js) as the entry and bundle that into an interpreted .js file. But I'm not trying to interpret my Node files, its my JSX files that need to be interpreted. Shouldn't I be trying to 'gulp' my JSX files, and then put them into their own directory with unique filenames, and then in my HTML templates write a  tag that includes those bundled files instead of my original .jsx files?

What is the strategy for keeping an organized file structure with different React components, and being able to just include them in a view template? Thanks

Here is my gulpfile.js
Right now it's creating a bundled server.js in the /build dir. I don't know what to do with that bundled file as it calls for client-side elements and I can't run it with node build/server.js

```html
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var watchify = require('watchify');
var reactify = require('reactify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('browserify', function(){
  var bundler = browserify({
    entries: ['./server.js'],
    transform: [reactify],
    debug: true,
    cache: {}, packageCache: {}, fullPaths: true
  });
  var watcher = watchify(bundler);
  
  return watcher
  .on('update', function(){
    var updateStart = Date.now();
    console.log('Updating!');
    watcher.bundle() // Create new bundle that uses the cache for high performance
    .pipe(source('server.js'))
    // This is where you add uglifying etc.
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
    console.log('Updated!', (Date.now() - updateStart) + 'ms');
  })
  .bundle()
  .pipe(source('server.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});

// Just run browserify
gulp.task('default', ['browserify']);
```

-- EDIT --

I've stripped down my gulpfile to do what I mentioned before. Simply 'reactify' my components and place their bundled counterparts into /build. But when I try to load this from my template, it can't find the file. Why is this?

```html
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var watchify = require('watchify');
var reactify = require('gulp-react');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('reactify', function(){
  return gulp.src('./public/javascripts/components/**')
    .pipe(reactify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
});

// Just run browserify
gulp.task('default', ['reactify']);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Do you want to render on the server or the client?

Comment: I want to render on the client, passing data from server.